# Deleting all whitespace in mathematica expression

Tags: string-manipulation

I have copied and pasted some output from a .log file into a mathematica notebook however the resulting output in the notebook contains many whitespaces between lines.

Is there a way to eliminate all whitespaces between characters in the string? I've tried StringReplace/ StringDelete in built routines but as a black box routine only accounts for a user defined number of whitespaces to remove rather than an arbitrary number (this number fluctuating from line to line in my rather long string output).

To be precise, I have something like `string1\n\n\n\n\n\nstring2\n\n\nstring3` where `\n` means a whitespace and the number of whitespaces in principle changes between differing strings. I'd like to write this as `string1string2string3`

If it's important `stringi` are combinations of `letters,^,*,+,- and [], e.g. string1 = [1/a]^-1*b` etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "string1\n\n\n\n\n\nstring2\n\n\nstring3";
StringDelete[s, WhitespaceCharacter]
```

> "string1string2string3"